# java script not working while validating the fields in php

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am validating 3 fields in html that they are empty or not .

the code is

```
<input type="file" id="uploadImage" name="image" />file1:
<input type="file" name="QRimage" id="File2" />file2:
<label for="name">Student information:</label>

<input  type="checkbox" name="person" id="person" >Yes
```

javascript:

```
   function validate()
       {
     var empt = document.forms["form1"]["image"].value; 
     var empt1 = document.forms["form1"]["QRimage"].value; 
     var empt2 = document.forms["form1"]["person"].value;  

     if (empt == "" && empt1 == "" && empt2 != "checked" )  
       {  
        alert("Please input a Value");  
       return false;  
       }
```

Problem: if those 3 fields are empty then its gives the alert message that ("please input a value") . but if checked the check box the allso its giving same message rather than going next page . where i am wrong ?

Comment: where you have applied the `validate()` ? provide complete form (HTML).

Comment: The value of `empt2` will never be `'checked'`, you've to compare `][person].checked` (which will be a boolean) instead of `value`. What has PHP to do with this question?

Comment: oh ho thank you @teemu you are true :)

Answer (score 3):

You want to access the `checked` property (which is a boolean) of the checkbox, not the value:

```
var isChecked = document.forms["form1"]["person"].checked;  

if (empt == "" && empt1 == "" && !isChecked) {  
    alert("Please input a Value");  
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: Sorry Jivings it was not working with "!isChecked" . i used empt2 == "" then its working . anyway thanks for helping